# Connecting speakers with audio splitters

Tags: speakers

If I were to get two of the same model of speaker and connect them with an audio splitter would it be louder than just one?

Comment: To my knowledge, any audio cable going through a splitter will result in the volume goes down.

Answer (score -1):

The question itself implies a fundamental lack of knowledge on the subject, so let me explain... not exactly briefly but hopefully simply...

A single speaker has three important considerations
Maximum power it can handle
The SPL [Sound Pressure Level] it can produce for a given input signal
Its impedance [resistance to electricity passing through it] SPL changes with power input & any speaker has an optimum efficiency, somewhere around ½ to ¾ its maximum handling (this can vary enormously, but just as a very broad figure).

A speaker must have an amplifier to drive it - provide an audio signal [alternating current voltage] at sufficient power that it makes the speaker physically move.

The amplifier's considerations are related...
The maximum power it can supply
What impedance it needs to see at the speaker. Too high & it cannot 'push' hard enough, too low & it will overheat as the power is 'sucked' out of it

If you have an amplifier matched to a speaker, then the speaker's maximum power-handling will be less than or similar to the amplifier can actually push. Its impedance will be the same as the amp is capable of handling. This is so the amp is never strained to distortion.

If you then wire two speakers to that amp using a splitter, then you are wiring in what is known as *parallel* - the signal is physically divided to go straight to both. [The alternative would be to wire them in *series*, through one speaker, then through the other, before wiring back to the amp.]

When this happens, the amplifier now sees only half the impedance - it is now endanger of overheating if turned up too far. It's working too hard because it has less 'pushing back' on it in terms of impedance.

Each speaker now sees half of the power compared to when it was solo. each speaker has an easier time of handling the power it's being sent - but as the amplifier is being sucked dry, it's more likely to be distorting. This is not good for the amp, neither is the distortion actually good for the speakers.

The speakers themselves are also now running less efficiently because they're now being asked to do half as much work as they were designed for. Their efficiency is not as good at this level [remember SPL from earlier] so each is actually wasting some of the amp's power as heat.

This is likely to result in you actually getting *less* volume from 2 speakers than you did from just one.

If you swapped to wiring in *series* rather than *parallel* then the amp would be working harder to push through twice as much impedance & you still wouldn't see any improvement. Without involving separately wired resistors, then only way to get the amp comfortable would be use 4 speakers, using a hybrid wiring that would give series/parallel... but we're now running way beyond sensible for such a simple setup.

So, **TL:DR** - it's not worth doing, you're not going to gain anything, & you also run the risk of shortening the amp's life-span.

Comment: Downvote 4 years after the fact, with no explanation. Was someone just miffed they couldn't do exactly what they wanted?